# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0b93397fa45180ee219aa69d3957daba.jpg'

Tags: python, flask

please an anyone help me , i am getting this error '[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0b93397fa45180ee219aa69d3957daba.jpg', if any one have a suggestion please , i want to get the picture after uploading and visioning !

```
import os
from uuid import uuid4
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
import io
from google.cloud import vision

app = Flask(__name__)
# app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="images")

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="json_key.txt"
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')
    # target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'static/')
    print(target)
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
            os.mkdir(target)
    else:
        print("Couldn't create upload directory: {}".format(target))
    print(request.files.getlist("file"))
    for upload in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print(upload)
        print("{} is the file name".format(upload.filename))
        filename = upload.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print ("Accept incoming file:", filename)
        print ("Save it to:", destination)
        upload.save(destination)
    with io.open(filename,'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()
        image = vision_client.image(content=content)

    labels = image.detect_labels()


    # return send_from_directory("images", filename, as_attachment=True)
    return render_template("complete_display_image.html", image_name=filename,labels=labels)

@app.route('/upload/<filename>')
def send_image(filename):
    return send_from_directory("images", filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  The posted code is not minimal, and is missing much of the error message (include trace-back).

Answer (score 0):

Use "destination" in the place of "filename"
io.open(**filename**,'rb') as image_file:

Comment: i did that but it gives me this error ==> ''AttributeError: 'ImageAnnotatorClient' object has no attribute 'image'"